# Display custom fields on post excerpt or teaser

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, excerpt

I have a custom Post Type I've created, and it also has some custom fields I created.  For full disclosure, I used the Pods framework to do this.

The Post Type can be tagged using a custom taxonomy.  When I visit the tag page for a given term in the taxonomy, e.g. `mysite.com/my_taxonomy/term`, the posts of Post Type show up as expected in an excerpt / teaser type of display.

What I would like to accomplish is to add my custom fields to this view.  Right now the only field that shows up is the title, author, and date (there is no 'body' field).  How can I add my custom fields to show up on this excerpt / teaser view of the content?

Comment: the first step is to found wich file of the theme is used. for that try the plugin "Query Monitor", it will show in the admin bar which templates are used and the order of search. http://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to retreive some meta data is knowing the name of the custom field, for my example I will use: listing, property and address; normally this can be done after **while (have_posts()) : the_post();**

```
$listing = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'listing', true);
$property = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'property', true);
$address = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'address', true);
```

then you can print the output like **echo $listing;** according your needs.

Comment: Awesome, great concise answer, with all the parts I need, and none of the parts I don't.  Was able to get it to work!

Comment: For displaying custom taxonomy terms, replacing `get_post_meta()` with `get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'taxonomy_name' )` works